# Is it possible to use an NSMutableString inside a UITextField to optimize the setting of text?

Tags: ios, optimization, uitextfield, nsmutablestring, settext

The use of Instruments Time Profiler has revealed that the setting of `UITextField`'s `text` property is very expensive in my app and so I would like to somehow optimise this. I thought it possible that mutating the existing text/`NSString` would be faster than setting a new `NSString` object each time, so I tried the following:

```
@interface MutableTextField : UITextField

- (NSMutableString*) mutableText;

@end

@implementation MutableTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSMutableString*) mutableText {
    return (NSMutableString*)self.text;
}

@end
```

The idea being that you would do something like the following rather than setting a new string:

```
[textField.mutableText replaceCharactersInRange:textRange withString:newText];
```

I quickly discovered that this won't work due to the `text` property being listed in the `UITextField` as `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text`. The **copy** modifier means that the `NSMutableString` that I set to the text is copied (as an immutable `NSString`) and then set - meaning that I cannot actually set a mutable string for a `UITextField`.

Can anyone see a way around this? Or am I stuck? If this is simply unachievable, then are there any other ways in which I could optimise the setting of a `UITextField`'s text?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a classic case of *over-optimization*. Have you actually profiled the code and and found it to be poorly-performing?

Setting a new string is most-liekly **faster** than replacing a substring because replacing a substring  needs to (by definition) find the original substring.

My guess is that your proposed changes will actually *decrease* the performance.

Comment: I had already used Instruments to profile my code and the setting of `UITextField`s' `text` has been identified as a bottleneck. Your suggestion that my proposed optimisation might decrease the performance could well be correct, but at the moment I have no way to actually implement the idea. Unless I can find a way to implement my idea I won't know for sure.

Comment: It could be a bottleneck because you are calling it too frequently. What mode of Instruments did you use, and how did you determine it was a bottleneck.

Comment: I used the Time Profiler setting and looked at the Running Time of each of my application's methods. The setText function was by far the most expensive method call in my highest ranking (slowest) method. The number of calls to it is definitely a problem, but is unavoidable due to the nature of my application.

Comment: Focusing on reducing the number of calls to setText it is the way to improve performance then. Even if setText is a little slow, I bet it's many orders of magnitude quicker than the time required for a user to actually read it. Let's say the text is a log display; you could have an internal NSMutableString which you build as the messages come in, but then rate-limit how often you call setText with that - perhaps a timer once a second or something is sufficient, or a separate method to apply the latest string to the UITextView